# why does my memory block show 'cd' in stead of '0' when i memset the value to be 0 in this memory address?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory

i am new to c++ and trying to learn the language from the ground up.
today i was learning about pointers and if i understand the code below correctly,

i am allocating 8 bytes of memory with a pointer named 'buffer'
and using memset function, i am putting 0 into each byte and i want the whole memory to be
filled with 0 so the full length of this is 8 so, i set it to be 0.

which if i run in debug mode, should return at this memory address of buffer

```
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

but instead, i get

```
cd cd cd cd cd cd cd cd
```

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char* buffer = new char[8];
    memset(buffer, 0, 8);

    delete[] buffer;
    std::cin.get();
}
```

Again, I come from javascript/python background and memory, heap, stack are all new to me.
please help me fix this...

Comment: Where exactly do you set your breakpoint? Before `memset` its uninitialized and after `delete` its undefined behavior.

Comment: Do you perhaps read after `delete[]`? Try printing the bytes from the code itself.

Comment: CD means uninitialised heap memory in visual studio https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)

Comment: thank you both! it works now and now i know what cd is!

Comment: you could still clarify the question and then someone could write an answer, even you could write the answer if you like. Comments are only for clarification (which was necessary) but not actually for answers

Comment: [When and why will a compiler initialise memory to 0xCD, 0xDD, etc. on malloc/free/new/delete?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/370195/995714)